# Yii2, DynaGrid, GridView: Setting the column width

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-extension

I try to set column width in DynaGrid:

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
    'columns' => [
         [
            'attribute' => 'shortcut',
            'width' => '75px',
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]);
```

See: http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid

It does not work. In the resulting table is the th element set correctly:

```
<th style="width:75px;" data-col-seq="0">...</th>
```

But in the colgroup is for the same column another value:

```
<colgroup>
    <col style="width: 32px;">
    ...
```

How can I change the width values in the colgroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have found one elegant solution, which works. The **minimum width of the search fields** in the head of the DynaGrid table is set in assets/dynagrid/index.css:

```
.form-control {
    min-width: 55px;
}
```

Pretty simple :-)

It solves the issue, which was reported by users. They could not see the input in the search field, if the column was too narrow.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following approaches (see the [suggestions of Ulises Trujillos Aguirre](https://plus.google.com/+Anton%C3%ADnSlej%C5%A1ka/posts/XJ6Bnw4dDuN)):

**!important modificator**

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'shortcut',
        'width' => '75px !important',
    ],
```

**CSS**

```
'columns' => [
    [
        'attribute' => 'shortcut',
        'width' => '75px !important',
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'col-width-75',
        ],
    ],
```

In assets/dynagrid/index.css:

```
.col-width-75 {
    width: 75px !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

In assets/dynagrid/index.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.col-width-75').css('width:75px !important');
    ...
});
```

I receive the following **output**:

```
<th style="width:75px !important;" data-col-seq="0">...</th>
...
<col class="col-width-75" style="width: 32px;">
```

In Developer Tools:

For **th**:

element.style {
    width: 150px !important;
}

for **col**:

element.style {
    <s>width: 43px;</s>
}

.col-width-150 {
    width: 150px !important;
}

It looks good, but in the browser has the column width 32px. So it looks like, that **the only working solution** is the incorrect one, which I wanted to avoid:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'shortcut',
    'label' => 'S&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;',
    'encodeLabel' => false,
],
```